# Publish layouts for channel entries, not just channel groups

Tags: add-on, custom-fields, publish-layout

I have [a project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljDyD.jpg) that requires a lot of individual fields specific to a page. I am looking to use a single field group, and hide unwanted fields from a client so they can edit a section on the one page rather than editing individual channel entries. From what I can tell, there are a couple of addons to go about this:

- **Entry Layout** - Which looks like it hasn't been updated in a long time, and on installation I'm getting this error (same as [another](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/entry-layout/viewthread/934)):

  ```
  Class Entrylayout_ext does not exist in (ext.entrylayout.php) 
  Filename: cp/addons_extensions.php
  Line Number: 107
  ```
- **Content Elements** - probably wouldn't work, with fieldtypes limited to their own (matrix is required)
- **Blueprints** - probably best candidate, but it's unclear if you can set fields on an individual entry basis. I would also like to lock the fields once set so they don't go screwing things up.

Each method has it's ups and downs. Any thought's on my best approach? Entry Layout feels like it would be the easiest fit but unfortunately it looks like it's dead.

What to do, what to do!?

Comment: FYI: Ben from Dukt has gone ahead and updated the Entry Layout addon - now works as expected.

Comment: FYI Blueprints lets you specify a publish layout based on the pages/structure *template* used - not entry. If you're using different templates for each entry, then this could work. Also, if your client doesn't have the appropriate permissions, they can't change the layout.

Comment: One add-on not mentioned here is [Single Entry](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/single-entry). It makes the one-channel-per-layout approach much more viable and user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

This bug in Entry Layout has just been fixed, download the latest release :

https://github.com/dukt/addon.eecms.entry-layout/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [**Entry Type addon**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type).

It allows you to set up a dropdown that shows/hides fields as needed.

Your dropdown can be your page name, when selected only the fields assigned to show with that dropdown selection will show.